# add the symbol of the end of a proof in beamer frame

Tags: beamer

I want to add the symbol of the end of a proof in a beamer frame as it is shown in the following picture

[image]

I try as follows

```
          \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
     \usepackage{pifont} 
     \mode<presentation>
      \usetheme{Madrid}
       \begin{document}

      \begin{frame}{Sketch of Proof}
      The steps of our theorem are the following:

       \textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

       \textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

       \textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

       \textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

          \[ \qedhere\]
      \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show a proof, use a `proof` environment and the qed sign will be there automatically:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sketch of Proof}

\begin{proof}
The steps of our theorem are the following:

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to manually place it, you can use `\qed`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sketch of Proof}
The steps of our theorem are the following:

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}} ....

\hfill \qed
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. My only question: is there a difference between `\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sketch of Proof}` and `\begin{frame}{Sketch of Proof}` ?

Comment: @Student Not much difference. I prefer the first because it is more flexible. For example you can do `\frametitle<1>{abc}\frametitle<2>{efg}` to switch between titles on different slides of the same frame.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\ding{228}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Sketch of Proof}
The steps of our theorem are the following:
\begin{itemize}
\item ...   
\item ...   
\item ...   
\item ...   
\end{itemize}
\hfill$\blacksquare$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```